# How can i make json file like this when i input

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

How can i make the **cart_items** like my expetation.. just it no more.. my problem just it :D
i just wanna make my **cart_items** like this.. hope you are can help me thanks. did I make the wrong method? and one more thing, i wanna make the **qty** inside the **cart_items**

**this is my expectation**

```
"cart": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "date": "12/10/2020",
  "store": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Dirumah Aja",
    "promo": 1
  },
  "cart_items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "product": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bakso Urat",
        "price": 10000,
        "promo": {
          "nama": "promo"
        }
      },
      "qty": 5
    }
  ]
}
]
```

**and this is what I got**

```
"cart": [
{
      "cart_items": {
        "name": "Steak Sapi Impor",
        "price": "38000",
        "stock": "4",
        "image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/francise-fb70a.appspot.com/o/steak.jpg?alt=media&token=46e0d769-96d3-440f-8edb-5fce2481ace0",
        "promo": 3,
        "id": 8,
        "qty": 1
      },
      "store": {
        "name": "Amanda Foods Store",
        "email": "amanda@food.com",
        "store_image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/francise-fb70a.appspot.com/o/full_hd_retina.jpeg?alt=media&token=3e602e86-661b-48ee-9e9c-af9f94a170d1",
        "product": [
          5,
          7,
          8,
          2
        ],
        "store_promo": 1,
        "location": {
          "street_name": "Jl. Kebon Gedang II B",
          "province": "Jawa Barat",
          "city": "Bandung",
          "post_code": "40285"
        },
        "id": 1
      },
      "date_order": "Nov 03 2020 08:48:03",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
```

**This is my data**

```
data() {
        return {
            promo_id: [],
            promo_partner: [],
            products: {},
            qty: 1,
            cart_items: [
                {}
            ]
        };
```

**and this is my method**

```
addToCart() {
            const date = (new Date()).toString().split(' ').splice(1,4).join(' ')

            this.products.cart_items = this.product;
            this.products.cart_items.qty = this.qty;
            this.products.store = this.partner;
            this.products.date_order = date;

            console.log(this.cart_items)

            axios
                .post("http://localhost:3000/cart/", this.products)
                .then(() => {
                    swal("Belanja Berhasil!", {
                        icon: "success",
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.push()` to add items to an array. You're replacing the array with `this.product`.

```
if (!this.products.cart_items) { // initialize cart_items if necessary
    this.products.cart_items = [];
}
this.products.cart_items.push({id: this.product.id, product: this.product, qty: this.qty});
```

Comment: I got an error like this

[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: You said your data contains `cart_items: [{}]` Doesn't that initialize it? I don't know vue.js.

Comment: You need to initialize it to an empty array earlier.

Comment: I updated the answer to initialize the property if it's not set yet.

Comment: hello @Barmar I do not know what to say, BUT ITSSSSSSSSSSSSS WORRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRKSSSSSSSSSSSSS


THANK YOU VERY MUCCCCCCCCCCCH :D

God Bless You